# Como incluir número de página en pdf generado con pdfmake?

Tags: pdf, jspdf

Estoy haciendo un reporte con pdfmake pero no encuentro la forma para incluir el número de página dimámico.

```
var pdf = {
    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
    pageOrientation: 'landscape',
        pageMargins: [ 30, 40, 70, 100 ],
    footer: {
            margin: [30, 20, 70, 10],
            columns: [
                    { text: usuario, alignment: 'left', fontSize:8},
                    { text: "Página: 1", alignment: 'center', fontSize:8},
                    { text: fechanow, alignment:'rigth', fontSize:8}
            ]
   },
   content: [
            {text: " ......."}
   ]
 };

 pdfMake.createPdf(pdf).download('archivo.pdf');
```

Comment: Hola Fernanda, ¿qué intentaste? ¿Puedes ofrecer algún tipo de código? ¿Qué dice la documentación? Lee [ask] y luego dale a [edit] para añadir más datos.

Comment: Hola Fernanda. Veo que has añadido el codigo pero has de explicar aun qué has intentado para añadir el numero y por qué falla. muestra algo por consola? el resultado no es el esperado ?

Comment: Deseo que el número de página sea dinámico en la medida que cambia de página. en este momento está fijo. Agradezco si me puede informar como hacerlo?